# Comparator comparing inner list field

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have a model like this

```java
class Person {
     Instant updateDate; // mandatory
     List<Account> accounts; // can be empty
}

class Account {
    Instant accountUpdateDate; // can be null
}
```

Suppose that I have a list of persons (each person contains account list that can be empty)

How can I get the person with max accountUpdateDate, otherwise I should retrieve the person with max updateDate.

Some thing like that

```java
Comparator<Person> UPDATE_DATE_COMPARATOR = Comparator
    .comparing(person -> person.getAccounts().stream().map(Account::getAccountUpdateDate)..., Comparator.nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))
    .thenComparing(Person::getUpdateDate));

Collections.max(personList, UPDATE_DATE_COMPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing that could be using `orElseGet` to separate out both the functionalities such as:

```
Supplier<Person> supplyMaxUpdateDatePerson = () -> personList.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getUpdateDate))
        .orElse(null); // or an identity value equivalent for 'Person'

Person maxAccountUpdateDateOrElseUpdateDate = personList.stream()
        .flatMap(person -> person.getAccounts().stream()
                .map(account -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(person, account.getAccountUpdateDate())))
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null) // otherwise you would always have a result in max
        .max(Comparator.comparing(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue))
        .map(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey)
        .orElseGet(supplyMaxUpdateDatePerson); // invoked only when all 'accountUpdateDate' are 'null'
```

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try